# Datagrid autogenerated columns custom template binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to apply a DataTemplate to my autogenerated columns. I can do this with a simple template. However I want a combobox with the text bound to the datagrid and an ellipse showing a colour based on this value through a converter.

I have tried two approaches. Firstly creating the template in codebehind and loading it through an xamlReader.

```
private void LeftPanel_AutoGeneratingColumn(
    object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = e.Column.Header;

        string xaml =
            "<DataTemplate xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:myView\">" +
            "<DataTemplate.Resources><local:goColorConverter x:Key=\"goColorConverter\" /></DataTemplate.Resources>" +
            "<ComboBox " +
           "SelectedValue=\"{Binding [" + e.Column.Header +
              "], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}\" Width=\"85\" " +
            "ItemsSource=\"{Binding Path=DataContext.goNoGo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}\">" +
            "<ComboBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\">" +
            "<Ellipse Fill=\"{Binding Converter={StaticResource goColorConverter}}\" Height=\"14\" Width=\"14\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Right\"/>" +
            "<TextBlock Text=\"{Binding}\" Padding=\"5 0\"/>" +
            "</StackPanel></DataTemplate></ComboBox.ItemTemplate></ComboBox></DataTemplate>";

        var sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
        var pc = new ParserContext();
        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        var datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);

        col.CellTemplate = datatemplate;
        col.CellEditingTemplate = datatemplate;
        e.Column = col;

        return;
    }
```

This gives me the correct binding to the data but I cant compile with the converter. I get error cannot create unknown type for my converter (lives in my code behind). I have read many posts about assemblies but could not use them to help me.

My second approach was to define the template in the xaml and apply it in my code behind. This makes the converter work but I don't know how to define my selected value binding as I don't know the column names prior to execution. I was hoping to use this [Josh smith FindName example](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/://) but I don't know how to access the content presenter.

code:

```
private void LeftPanel_AutoGeneratingColumn(
    object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = e.Column.Header;

        col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["goDropColumn"];
        col.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["goDropColumn"];

        //Do magic here to get combo box and update its binding

        e.Column = col;
        return;
    }
```

xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="goDropColumn">
    <ComboBox Name="combo" Width="85" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.goNoGo,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding ???}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource goColorConverter}}"
                           Height="14" Width="14"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Padding="5 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am not married to my approach and am new to WPF and c# so if the method is totally wrong please let me know. I feel the second approach is a lot cleaner and would work if I could change my binding marked with ??? to the column name.

[Another possibly relevant article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b2e94b7-3c44-4642-8acc-851de5285062/bind-datatable-to-wpf-datagrid-using-datagridtemplatecolumn-programatically?forum=wpf) but I don't have a custom datatype, I just want selectedValue bound to the column.

UPDATED CODE as requested by MachineLearning:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
col.Header = e.Column.Header;


string xaml =
    @"<DataTemplate x:Key=""goDropColumn""
        xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:RP_SIL.View;assembly=RP_SIL.View""
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x = ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
        <ComboBox SelectedValue=""{Binding [" + e.Column.Header + @"], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}""
            Width=""85""
            ItemsSource=""{Binding Path=DataContext.goNoGo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <local:goColorConverter x:Key=""goColorConverter""></local:goColorConverter>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
                        <Ellipse Fill=""{Binding Converter={StaticResource goColorConverter}}"" Height=""14"" Width=""14"" HorizontalAlignment=""Right""/>
                        <TextBlock Text=""{Binding}"" Padding=""5 0""/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>";
//Binding Converter={StaticResource goColorConverter
var sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
var pc = new ParserContext();
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("local", "clr-namespace:RP_SIL.View;assembly=RP_SIL.View");
var datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);

col.CellTemplate = datatemplate;
col.CellEditingTemplate = datatemplate;
```

Massive Thanks to Machine Learning for his time and solving the problem!

Comment: Try `xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:RP_SIL.View;assembly=RP_SIL""`

Comment: This **works** `xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:RP_SIL.View;assembly=RP-SIL""` you can find the correct assembly name in the project properties: in this case it has a dot instead of the underscore. Now please try and accept my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome.
There is a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824493/datatemplate-with-converter-in-code-behind#comment9537280_7824493) to load the converter in the xaml.

This is the code from my demo, as an example for you.

```
string MyBoolName = "IsEnabled";
string MyTextName = "Title";
string xaml =
 @"<DataTemplate
xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:Templating;assembly=Templating""
x:Key=""goDropColumn"">
                <ComboBox Name=""combo"" Width=""85"" ItemsSource=""{Binding Path=DataContext.MyThings,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}""

       > <!-- SelectedValue=""{Binding ???}"" -->
<ComboBox.Resources>
<local:BrushColorConverter x:Key=""goColorConverter""></local:BrushColorConverter>
</ComboBox.Resources>


                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
                                <Ellipse Fill=""{Binding ""{Binding "+ MyBoolName + @"}"",  Converter={StaticResource goColorConverter}}""
                           Height=""14"" Width=""14"" />
                                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding " + MyTextName + @"}"" Padding=""5 0""/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>";
```

Comment: Is this what you asked for? Could you provide a feedback or accept my answer if it is working as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your time you have correctly identified my problem. But no joy, this encounters the same error I had before.  Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:MyNameSpace;assembly=MyNameSpace}BrushColorConverter'. The converter and namespace is the same as my code-behind, do I need to do something to make it a separate assembly or something. the `;assembly=Templating` means nothing to me. Have I missed a step? Or do I need to use something different to load my xml (see first code snippet).I added more info so deleted previous comment as couldnt edit

Comment: My final comment is that there must be some errors in the names you wrote for the namespace or the assembly and it's impossible to spot them without seeing the full project (where you have defined them).

Comment: FIXED !!!! your assembly name is RP-SIL You can read it from your project properties. It's written with minus not underscore (while the namespace is underscore) Just replace minus - instead of undersocre in the assembly name line 89.  Now please **accept** my answer :-)